# I want to save credential( OAuth2.0) in the project. not on disk. - google sheet api

Tags: spring-boot, google-api, google-oauth, credentials

I added google-api for spread sheet.
But now, I want to save credential on my project, not on the server.

This is part of code.

```
private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"),
                                                                    ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");
```

The code saves credential on the disk.
But I want to save on my project. maybe under resources folder.

How can I save it?

env. spring-boot

Comment: have you tried changing the data store directory?

Comment: Yes, I added directory under src/main/java/resources.
In my problem, getting file_store_dir path.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I answer my question.
First, I modified my source where the application read file directory.

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File( resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/local").getURI().getPath());
    FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
```

yes, I use resourceLoader.

Thanks.